# $(\mathbb{CP}^1)^n/S_n \overset{\sim}{\to} \mathbb{CP}^n$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request

Can someone refer to me a source that describes the construction of a homeomorphism $$(\mathbb{CP}^1)^n/S_n \overset{\sim}{\to} \mathbb{CP}^n?$$I am not an algebraic geometrer and I would like to see this result worked out...

Comment: Think about the elementary symmetric polynomials.

Comment: I found this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/214612/understanding-the-cartesian-product-of-complex-projective-lines

Comment: This does however remind me of something cute: http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/symplectomorphism#a_curious_example_volumes_of_balls

Comment: Here is the usual geometric construction. Embed the projective line in projective n space as a rational normal curve.  Then there is a 1-1 correspondence between hyperplanes and unordered sets of n points on the rational curve given by intersection.  This is a homeomorphism from unordered sets of n points on the projective line to the dual space of hyperplanes in n space, which is homeomorphic to the projective n space itself.